A finite graph $\Gamma$ under certain conditions has maximal subtree with at most $2n-3$ edges
In the book "Topological Methods in Group Theory", the author (R. Geoghegan) states the following theorem:

Proposition 9.5.1.
a) The simplicial complex $K_n$ has dimension $2n-3$; in
fact every simplex is a face of a $(2n − 3)$-simplex.
b) The stabilizer of every simplex is ﬁnite.
c) $K_n$ is ﬁnite mod $Out(F_n)$.

$K_n$ is a flag complex formed by marked graphs. It is described in Page 216, but it is not so important to my question.
He lefts the proof as an exercise. I can prove (b) and (c). For the item (a) he states a claim as a hint. With the hint, I'm able to prove (a), but I could not prove the hint.

Hint. Let $\Gamma$ be a ﬁnite graph in which every vertex has valence $\geq 3$ and $\pi_1(\Gamma, v) \simeq F_n$. Then any maximal tree in $\Gamma$ has at most $2n - 3$ edges. Moreover,
there exists such a graph for which maximal trees have precisely $2n - 3$ edges.

I'm not sure how to use the hypothesis $\pi_1(\Gamma,v) \simeq F_n$. I was trying to use the Structure Theorem of Bass-Serre theory but I cannot conclude anything (and $\Gamma$ may not be connected).

Without loss of generality, suppose $G$ is connected (by considering any connected component if needed). Let $V$ and $E$ denote the number of vertices and the number of edges of $G$, respectively.
One can compute the fundamental group $\pi_1(G, v)$ (which is, up to isomorphism, the same for every $v \in G$, by connectedness) as follows: given any maximal tree $T$ of $G$, if $m$ denotes the number of edges in $G \setminus T$, then the quotient space $G/T$ (obtained by collapsing the contractible $T$ to a point, so $G/T$ is homotopy equivalent to $G$) is homeomorphic to a wedge of $m$ circles, hence
$$ \pi_1(G, \ast) \cong \pi_1(G/T, \ast) \cong \pi_1(\wedge^m S^1, \ast) \cong F_m.$$
Since we assume here $\pi(G, \ast) \cong F_n$, this means that $m=n$ for every maximal tree $T \subset G$.
Let $t$ denote the number of edges in a (connected) maximal tree $T$. From the previous paragraph, we have $E = t+n$. Given a root vertex $v_0 \in T$, for every other $v \in T$, there exists a unique 'injective' path from $v_0$ to $v$ inside $T$. These unique paths induce an orientation to every edge of $T$, so every edge has a 'source endpoint' and a 'target endpoint'. Since there is a bijection between edges of $T$ and target endpoints, we see that $T$ has $t+1$ vertices. But $T$ contains every vertex of $G$, so $S = t+1$.
For any graph, the average valence $\bar{V}$ of $G$ is $2E/S$. By assumption here, every vertex has valence at least three, so $\bar{V} \ge 3$. Thus $2E \ge 3S$, i.e., $2(t+n) \ge 3(t+1)$, i.e., $2n-3 \ge t$. This proves the first claim in the hint.
For the second claim in the hint, we see from the previous paragraph that $t = 2n-3$ if and only if $\bar{V} = 3$, i.e., if every vertex of $G$ has valence $3$. Also, $S = 2(n-1)$ and $E = 3(n-1)$. For $n\ge 2$, we can recursively produce examples of graphs $G_n$ having those properties. For $n=2$, $G_2$ has the form of a '$\theta$'. Assume inductively that $G_n$ has been produced and ressembles a 'central' maximal tree $T_n$ inscribed in a circle, with all of the 'outer' edges of $T_n$ touching the circle, thereby dividing the circle into $n$ segments. To produce $G_{n+1}$ replace one of the 'outer' edge of $T_n$ (of the form '$|$') by the form '$Y$': doing so, three new edges and three new vertices (of valence $3$) are produced, and the circle is now divided into $n+1$ segments.

$G$ is connected, with loss of generality, but we have to assume it, since the result is false, if $G$ is not connected.

@ameg Without loss of generality. The fundamental group probes the connected component of the vertex, even when the space is disconnected. There is no 'exhausting' tree (i.e. one containing every vertex) in a disconnected graph, but the notion of maximal tree (with respect to the order relation given by inclusion of trees) is the next best thing (and so, if desired, one can speak of an 'exhausting' forest of maximal trees). The hint is phrased in such a way that the (same) conditions hold for every connected components of the graph, so we can wlog take the graph connected.

Yes, by reading something differently as it is written anything you want can be true.

@ameg Or can be false ;) The condition $\pi_1(G, v) \cong F_n$ is assumed true here for every vertex too. So you have a condition saying something about the fundamental group of each connected component, and you deduce something about the sizes of the maximal tree in every connected component. Perfectly sensible to me.

Connectivity is part of the definition of a marked graph.
